# Como hago para programar una orden todos los dia en MQL5?

Tags: codificación, mql4

mis conocimientos son pobre en MQL5, quiero que todos los dia a la 11 hora de new york se me haga una venta en USDCHF (solo una venta) a precio del mercado y que solo se cierre cuando se llegue a un Stoploss de -30 pips o un Takeprofit de +30 pips es para virtualizar grafico pasado osea para backtester. alguien me da la solucion?

```
// Asesor Experto para vender al precio de mercado en MT5
// Este código debe ser colocado en un archivo con extensión .mq5

// Función de inicialización del asesor experto
int OnInit()
{
    // Realizar la venta al precio de mercado
    SellAtMarket();
    
    return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

// Función para realizar la venta al precio de mercado
void SellAtMarket()
{
    // Obtener el símbolo actual
    string symbol = Symbol();
    
    // Obtener el precio de mercado actual
    double marketPrice = MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_BID);
    
    // Colocar una orden de venta al precio de mercado
    OrderSend(symbol, OP_SELL, 0.01, marketPrice, 0, 0, 0, "Venta al precio de mercado", 0, 0, clrNONE);
}
```